# Symfony Multiple choice on entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

i try to make a status field in my entity with multiple choice.
i want that user can have three choices of the status: 'to do' , 'done' and 'to review' .
what's the best doctrine type ?
how can i do this to display the values on a select input?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage of ChoiceType is to provide an array of choices, where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value:

```
$form->add('state',ChoiceType::class,[
    'choices' => [
        'To do' => 'to do',
        'Done' => 'done',
        'To review' => 'to review',
    ]
]);
```

Inside your entity class your field will be a simple string field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
 private $status;
```

You could go as far as using [Mysql Enums](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) since there are only three possible values, but I find that an unnecessary overhead because when creating an entity through a form, Symfony will accept only these three values as possible values.
Finally, you could also add some validation to make sure this field always holds a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can i declare the field in my entity class with orm annotation ? This will be a simple string field or an array .... !?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ChoiceType`:

```
    $form->add('state',ChoiceType::class,[
        'choices' => [
            0 => 'to do',
            1 => 'done',
            2 => 'to review',
        ]
    ])
```

More in symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html